# When checking Accessibility using Wave Tool for mat-select that uses mat-label , getting Orphaned form label accessibility warning

Tags: angular, label, angular-material, accessibility, section508

A drop down is created with mat-select and a label for dropdown is added with mat-label. On checking the accessibility using Wave Evaluation Tool chrome extension, getting Orphaned form label Warning. (Label not associated with proper form element)

Wave Tool : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wave-evaluation-tool/jbbplnpkjmmeebjpijfedlgcdilocofh

What is the expected behavior?
Orphaned form label warning should not appear

What is the current behavior?
Orphaned form label warning apeard

What are the steps to reproduce?
Syntax to Reproduce the issue

[Syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2jCD.png)

What is the use-case or motivation for changing an existing behavior?
We are trying to fix accessibility issues in our project and we are relying on Material Designs.

Which versions of Angular, Material, OS, TypeScript, browsers are affected?
Angular - 5.2.0 , Material - 5.2.3 , OS- Windows , TypeScript - 2.5.3 , Browser - Google Chrome

Is there anything else we should know?
Tried Adding id in mat-select /adding for in mat-label.
Also tired using placeholder.
[Wave Tool Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gpjn.png)

Answer (score 0):

What code is generated by material?  If I look at the second example, "Form field appearance variants", on https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview, it generates

```html
<input _ngcontent-c25="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" matinput=""
  placeholder="Placeholder" id="mat-input-2" aria-describedby="mat-hint-0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
<span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper">
  <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c21-7 mat-empty mat-form-field-empty ng-star-inserted" for="mat-input-2" aria-owns="mat-input-2">
    <mat-label _ngcontent-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted">Legacy form field</mat-label>
  </label>
</span>
```

Notice that the `<input>` has an ID of "mat-input-2" and that the following `<label>` has a `for` attribute that points to "mat-input-2".  That is the correct way to associate a label with an input.  Without this association, you'll probably get the orphaned label message.